# Mysql self join help needed

Tags: mysql

I have following table structure:

```
uid    | product_code
---------------------
00001  | 'tb'
00001  | 'im' 
00001  | 'ip'
00002  | 'tb'
00002  | 'im'
```

I want a selfjoin query that will show me those uids which have all three product codes 'mg','ip','tb' with them. i.e only 00001 will be displayed. How can it be done?

Comment: thank you all, for helping me. I had to reject count of product_code related answers because I am going to need specific product code in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sj1.uid FROM tbl sj1 
    JOIN tbl sj2 ON sj1.uid = sj2.uid 
    JOIN tbl sj3 ON sj1.uid = sj3.uid
WHERE sj1.product_code = 'tb'
    AND sj2.product_code = 'im'
    AND sj3.product_code = 'mg'
```

should work also if you have more product codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
select uid from mytable 
where product_code in ('mg','ip','tb') 
group by uid having count(distinct(product_code))=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only three product code
`Select * from table group by uid having count(uid) =` 3